# AAC audio extracted using ffmpeg gets shortened when converted to WAV

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, conversion

I have an .mp4 video encoded in H264 and AAC. I extracted the audio so that I could make some changes in Audacity and use ffmpeg to combine the video and new audio. But it turned out that while the video was 12:40.92 long, the extracted audio was only 12:30.59 long. The shortening happened when I converted the audio from AAC to WAV -- didn't matter whether ffmpeg converted, or I just extracted an .m4a file using ffmpeg then imported it into Audacity.

When I created the new video file, I was able to solve the problem by lengthening the audio (`-filter:a "atempo=0.986424"`). But I don't understand what was "wrong" with the extracted audio. Audacity and ffmpeg both shortened, so it doesn't appear to be anyone's "fault".

Anyone have any thoughts? Is there a property in the .m4a file controlling this? If so, how can I view that property?

Details:

`ffprobe` reports the video's duration as 12:40:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
Duration: 00:12:40.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1432 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1245 kb/s, 29.56 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 177 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

If I extract the audio (`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -c:a copy audio.m4a`), the .m4a filesize is 17,095,597 B and the duration is 12:40:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'audio.m4a':
Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
Duration: 00:12:40.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 179 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 177 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Now we convert the .m4a to WAV (`ffmpeg -i audio.m4a audio.wav`):

```
Output #0, wav, to 'audio.wav':
Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    ISFT            : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
    encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 pcm_s16le
size=  129300kB time=00:12:40.91 bitrate=1392.0kbits/s speed= 964x    
video:0kB audio:129300kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000059%
```

But ffprobe now shows the duration has been shortened to 12:30:

```
Input #0, wav, from 'audio.wav':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
Duration: 00:12:30.59, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

Comment: The audio stream likely doesn't represent a continuous timeline. In MP4/M4A, those gaps were preserved using timestamps but WAV doesn't have timestamps. Add `-af aresample=async=1` for WAV extraction..

Comment: @Gyan Thank you very much. You're correct -- I printed some frames w/ ffprobe and found small audio gaps. async fixed it, although I did have to bump it up to 1000. If you re-post, I can mark as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ffmpeg -i {video} -async  1 -f {fmt} {audio}`.
This is the way to sync the timestamp between `source-video` and `target-audio`.

Comment: This area is for answers, not further questions.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to extract the aac audio?, this is imposible.

the audio time is 00:12:30.59 (00 hours, 12 minits and 30 seconds and 59 miliseconds)
the video time is 00:12:40.92, start: 0.000000 (00 hours, 12 minits and 40 seconds and 92 miliseconds)

you have to copy the audio into a new file like only_audio.mp4 and the same for video into a only_video.mp4 try some like this

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c copy -an only_video.mp4
```

> will created a file called only_video.mp4 with a duration of 00:12:40.92

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vn -c copy -strict -2 only_audio.mp4

> will created a file called only_audio.mp4 with a duration of 00:12:30.59

ok... edit your only_audio.mp4 file... and check if the file edited is "aac" and his time, (in theory have to be) 00:12:40.92

TE CONCLUTION; THE AUDIO FILE IS 00:00:10.33 SECONDS MORE SMALLED than only_video.mp4...

> yo have to use **-itsoffset**

```
ffmpeg -i "only_video.mp4" -itsoffset 00:00:10.33 -i "only_audio.mp4" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -strict -2 "problem_end.mp4"
```

ok amiwo, afloja y largate unos dolares que i want the ultimate mac, if this was ok, send a email xear.div@gmail.com thanks regards!